# Can't find file on classpath grails war/tomcat

Tags: file, tomcat, grails, classpath

I have put a file in my grails-app/conf package called size_config.xml  .  When the war is built then unpacked the file shows up in WEB-INF/classes with the expected name.  However, when I try to reference the file in my application it claims that the file is not found.  I've tried all combinations that I can think would be logical in trying to reference including:

```
new File("WEB-INF/classes/size_config.xml")
new File("classes/size_config.xml")
new File("size_config.xml")
new File("grails-app/conf/size_config.xml")
```

and none of these seem to work.  When I run my local integration tests I use "grails-app/conf/size_config.xml" and it finds the file just fine.  Since the file is being packed up fine, I'm assuming its not a deploy config issue, but rather some minor item I'm failing to see.  Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out:

```
def servletContext = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.servletContext 
def file = servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/size_config.xml")
```

Comment: Trying it out at the moment.  Still works locally, so definitely didn't hurt anything...Just waiting for build and deploy.

Comment: @Joseph if the first one doesnt work. try the second. and let me know! then I will edit my answer!

Comment: The second solution worked.  Thank you very much.  You saved me many more hours of trying random solutions!

Comment: @Joseph awesome dude! I will just leave the second option! for further searching!

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to treat classpath resources as local disk file system paths using `File` while relying on default working directory which is not controllable from inside the application. This is not right. You need to obtain it as a classpath resource. The `/WEB-INF/classes` is by default covered by the classpath. So you just need to obtain `"size_config.xml"` from the classpath.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream sizeConfig = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("size_config.xml");
// ...
```

Comment: If thats the case, the above not working would indicate an issue with setup?  I just double checked and both locally and out on the server, size_config.xml is under /WEB-INF/classes .  Any thoughts on what would cause it to not get loaded to the classpath correctly?

Comment: I noticed that I had a typo in my example. It should use `_` instead of `-` in filename. I'll fix the answer, but did you take this into account? By the way, resources are not "loaded to" the classpath. The "classpath" is just a collection of local disk file system paths where the JVM should scan for files which are to be loaded by the classloader.